# How to `dismiss` several pages in one time in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

If you have ever developed iOS app, you will know the `dismiss(animated:)` makes the `UINavigationController`  move out of the screen from below, and it takes its child controllers together. I don't know how to implement it in Flutter:
Page `A` jump to page `B` with transition `down to up`, page `B` jump to page `C` with default transition `right to left`. Now I don't know how to go back to page `A` with transition `up to down`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil` to navigate to `A`. This would remove `B` and `C`.

From the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html#:%7E:text=Push%20the%20given%20route%20onto,the%20RoutePredicate%20returned%20from%20ModalRoute.), pushAndRemoveUntil is used to:

> Push the given route onto the navigator, and then remove all the
> previous routes until the predicate returns true.

Comment: Yes, we opened new page `A`, but it is not return. Note that I am saying return, with animation `up to down` like `dismiss(animated:)` in iOS.

Comment: For adding 'page route transition' like a up to down you can refer Flutter documentation here (https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation).

Comment: A easier way would be using `page_transition` package.

Comment: It seems that the `page_transition` package only implemented transition in pushing. Today I realized that in iOS, we are controlling `UINavigationController` instance directly, but there is no such class in Flutter!